# How to deploy SNAPSHOT with sources and JavaDoc?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I want to deploy sources and javadocs with my snapshots. This means that I want to automize the following command:

```
mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar deploy
```

Just to execute:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

I don't want to have javadoc/sources generation executed during the `install` phase (i.e. local builds).

I know that source/javadoc plugins can be synchronized with the execution of the `release` plugin but I can't figure out how to wire it to the snapshots releases.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

```xml
<build>
  <plugins> 
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>attach-sources</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals><goal>jar-no-fork</goal></goals> 
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin> 
      <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId> 
      <executions> 
        <execution> 
          <id>attach-javadocs</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals><goal>jar</goal></goals> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
    </plugin>
    <plugin> 
      <!-- explicitly define maven-deploy-plugin after other to force exec order -->
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId> 
      <executions> 
        <execution> 
          <id>deploy</id>
          <phase>deploy</phase>
          <goals><goal>deploy</goal></goals> 
        </execution> 
      </executions> 
    </plugin>
  </plugins> 
</build>
```

See [Sonatype's OSS parent POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/5/oss-parent-5.pom) for a complete example.

Comment: I'm using this setup, and it works quite well. However I had two small issues: one, generated sources are not included in the "jar" goal, you'll need "jar-no-fork". Two, there is a bug in the release plugin that will cause to generate the release sources twice (and therefore deploeyed twice, which will lead to problems with repository managers)

Comment: `maven-source-plugin:jar` attaches to the `package` phase by default, so you could leave off `<phase>verify</phase>` and accomplish the same thing. Besides I'm not sure why you'd attach this to verify anyway as that phase is intended for "package the project and run integration tests".

Comment: @mglauche @matt thanks for your comments. I've just made the appropriate changes.

Comment: Sorry guys, but maven-deploy-plugin (as opposed to the release-plugin) doesn't support <arguments> element in <configuration>. So the configuration in your answer doesn't work for deploy (only for release).

Comment: @Henryk I've proposed a completely different approach now. Simply try to bind both plugins to the deploy phase, no profile needed. Untested but *should* work. The problem is that Maven doesn't guarantee any order of plugin execution. Therefore, the deploy plugin could execute before sources and javadoc jars have been built.

Comment: @Henryk Ok, I've explicitly added maven-deploy-plugin as well as maven seems (or tries) to guarantee execution in the oder the plugins are defined in the POM. It might require some experimenting though.

Comment: It works! @sfussenegger Kudos for you :) I tried to bind doc/src to deploy phase before but without your phase sequence trick it didn't work. Thanks again.

Comment: you have wrong execution id of maven-deploy-plugin it should be default-deploy

Comment: @Hurda "default-<goalName>" execution IDs are a feature introduced in Maven 2.2.0. I haven't used it yet, but it's certainly not necessary. Using some random unique ID works just fine.

Comment: here's the related documentation: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html

Comment: using random id creates new execution I thought you would want to "remap" the default one execution

Comment: with newer maven version 3.0.5+, you just need to add the plugins without specifying a phase.

Comment: This isn't working for me with Maven 3.1.1. Deploy plugin happens before javadoc and source despite the order they appear in the pom. Anyone else running into this?

Answer (score 68):

The article referred to by Dan also mentions another approach that works without modifying poms AND won't go away anytime soon:

> mvn clean **javadoc:jar source:jar** install

Which works fine with Maven 3+, along with...

> mvn clean **javadoc:jar source:jar** deploy

Which I have tested from Jenkins deploying to Nexus.

This approach was nice because I only had to modify some Jenkins jobs and didn't need to mess with my poms.

Comment: Thanks for a pom-free solution! 

Note that **javadoc:jar** and/or **source:jar** must appear before **install** or **deploy**, or the extra jars won't be "attached" to the deployment.

Comment: FWIW these options also work with `package`: `mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar package`

Comment: This is the good answer, since it tells you the exact command to build and upload sources and javadoc to your repo.

Answer (score 50):

Just to add an alternative that doesn't require you to muck with plugin configuration:

```
mvn -DperformRelease=true [goals]
```

Credit goes to mcbeelen from http://sea36.blogspot.com/2009/02/attaching-javadocs-and-sources-to-maven.html?showComment=1314177874102#c6853460758692768998

Comment: I'd like to mention that this feature might go away in a future release of Maven (possibly Maven-4?).  Check out the comment here in the Maven Super POM's profile section: http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.1/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html