# Upload Maven package's sources to MyGet repository

Tags: eclipse, maven, myget

I am using Eclipse and Maven to create a Maven package that is uploaded to MyGet to be consumed by other users.  I would like to make it so that when my package is referenced as a dependency and therefore downloaded from MyGet, the source attachment is also downloaded.

I've seen this happen with, for example, the JOGL library - when my Maven project in Eclipse references JOGL, I end up with the following files in the ~/.m2/repository subdirectory associated with JOGL (among others):

- jogl-all-main-2.3.2.jar
- jogl-all-main-2.3.2-sources.jar

And in Eclipse, if I right click on the jogl-all-main-2.3.2.jar library and choose Properties, it shows the source attachment as `jogl-all-main-2.3.2-sources.jar` located in my `.m2` folder.  I don't believe that I did anything to select that file as the source attachment; I think it happened automatically.

When I upload my package to MyGet, it allows me to upload one or more jar files, but it expects each jar file to be a Maven package including a pom.xml file, so I can't upload the sources jar file to MyGet directly.

Perhaps this is a limitation of MyGet, in that it doesn't allow me to upload the sources in parallel.  I'm not familiar enough with Maven to know if it's something that I need to specify in the `pom.xml` for my package.

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725668/how-to-deploy-snapshot-with-sources-and-javadoc). I believe MyGet should support standard Maven's **mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar deploy** command

Comment: @udalmik So are you suggesting that using `mvn` to deploy rather than MyGet's web interface will allow me to deploy the jar file containing the sources?

Comment: yes, I would try this way, with adding your MyGet repo to config

Comment: @udalmik This seems like a good way to go.  I've gotten `maven deploy` to successfully push the package up to the repository.

But it's not uploading the sources / javadocs.  Should I deploy these using the `deploy-file` command separately, or is there a way to make it happen automatically when the `deploy` command is executed?

Comment: @udalmik: I was able to get this to work using `mvn deploy` instead of using MyGet's GUI to upload packages.  If you want to write up an answer, I will mark it as the apporoved answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725668/how-to-deploy-snapshot-with-sources-and-javadoc). I believe MyGet should support standard Maven's command:

```
mvn clean javadoc:jar source:jar deploy
```

So please try configure your MyGet's repo as registry and upload your packages using Maven's CLI intead of MyGet's GUI.