# Generate Javadoc and sources for the library

Tags: java, interface, javac, javacompiler

I have an Interface and a Class that implements it in a Project (say Project1):

```
public interface MainInterface {
    /**
     * some description goes here
     * @param foo
     * @param bar
     * @param ufo
     */
    void someAbstractMethod(int foo, int bar, int ufo);
}
```

```
public class MainInterfaceImpl implements MainInterface {
    @Override
    public void someAbstractMethod(int foo, int bar, int ufo) {
        //blah blah
    }   
}
```

I have built this project using maven and using it as a dependency in another Project(say Project2), In Project 2, I am trying to create an object like this:

[![Implementation in project 2][1]][1]

Its losing the variable names, Is there a way I can persist the variable names? I think this is achievable since all the methods of java.util.List interface have their argument names intact.

[![List interface implementation][2]][2]

What am I missing here?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfty.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCdP.png

P.S: I don't really understand how this image attachment works with stackoverflow, please feel free to edit the question to keep the images in-line.

Comment: publish and download javadoc/and or sources for your library.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm new to this :)

Comment: You need to generate sources and javadoc. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725668/how-to-deploy-snapshot-with-sources-and-javadoc) should help with the required configuration for maven. If you have generated them, just download as mentioned in the other comment.

Comment: The subject doesn't make sense and doesn't seem related to the issue.